# How to create an array of objects with all objects from multiple arrays?

Tags: javascript

Given de following arrays:

```
const classes = [
  {
    students: [
       Student1,
       Student2,
    ]
  },
  {
    students: [
       Student3,
       Student4,
    ]
  }
]
```

What's the best way performance-wise to generate an array of objects with a similar structure to this:

```
const allStudents = [
  Student1,
  Student2,
  Student3,
  Student4
]
```

Comment: I tried:

```
const allStudents = classes.reduce((acc, class) => {
      if (!class.students) {
        return acc;
      }

      return [...acc, ...class.students];
    });
```

however, it's not working

Comment: classes.flatMap((e) => e.students)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Please note:** Donot use reserved keyworks such ass `class` as a variable name.

`Array.reduce` implementation

```js
const classes = [
  { students: [ 'Student1', 'Student2' ] },
  { students: [ 'Student3', 'Student4' ] }
];
const allStudents = classes.reduce((acc, cls) => {
  acc = cls.students ? acc.concat(cls.students) : acc;
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(allStudents)
```

`Array.flatMap` implementation.

```js
const classes = [
  { students: [ 'Student1', 'Student2' ] },
  { students: [ 'Student3', 'Student4' ] }
]
const allStudents = classes.flatMap((cls) => cls.students ? cls.students : []);
console.log(allStudents);
```

Comment: Perfect, flatMap is the ideal solution to my problem

Comment: In my code I don't use "class", I only use to my example.

Answer (score 2):

```
const classes = [
  {
    students:[
   "Student1",
   "Student2"
    ]
  },
  {
    students:[
   "Student3",
   "Student4"
    ]
  }
]

const n=classes.flatMap(x=>x.students.flatMap(i=>i))
console.log(n)
```

This would be recommended keeping performance in mind it is faster then regular for loop and ... many online sources say flatMap is better in terms of performance

Comment: `classes.flatMap(x => x.students)` will be enough.

Comment: Actually then it will give a 2D array so a second is needed to get it to a 1D array

Comment: [ [ 'Student1', 'Student2' ], [ 'Student3', 'Student4' ] ] this becomes the output without the second flatmap

Answer (score 0):

```
const allStudents = classes.reduce((acc,curr)=>{
  return [...acc,...curr.students]
},[])
```

I think this is a simple and easy to understand way to group students in one array.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const classes = [
  {
    students: ['Student1', 'Student2'],
  },
  {
    students: ['Student3', 'Student4'],
  },
];
const allStudents = classes.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  return [...acc, ...curr.students];
}, []);
console.log(allStudents);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's what I did, hope it helped:

```js
const classes = [
  {
    students: [
    'Student1',
    'Student2',
    ]
  },
  {
    students: [
    'Student3',
    'Student4',
    ]
  }
  ];

  var newArray = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++){
    var tempArray = Object.values(classes[i]);
    for(var j = 0; j < tempArray[0].length; j++){
      newArray.push(tempArray[0][j]);
    }
  }

  console.log(newArray);
```